# Python reading CSV-File universal-newline mode

Tags: python, csv, newline

I have a problem reading my csv-file.

I already got a solution for another csv-file (from a webpage) that always worked since. 
I am using this code:

```
    def readCSV(link):
        data = []
        ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
        csvFile = csv.reader(ftpstream.read().decode('latin-1').split('\n'))
        newData = [line for line in csvFile]  
        data.extend(newData)
        return data
```

But now it won't take this solutiion. It always says:

```
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

I found a couple of solutions but implementing them always ended up in not finding the file, although it is found when I am not using split and not the "rU", but then the output is  not usable.

I also tried changing the split to `';'` or other but always ended up with the same problem.